# Flutter FutureBuilder throws error, but on simulation it works as expected

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous, dart, null

I'm a beginner to Flutter and currently I'm having a problem with correctly implementing FutureBuilder in flutter.
I'm trying to build a user page, where I have my user information stored in Firebase, and every time I access the user page it retrieves the current user data and shows the data on the page. Here's the code I've written for the implementation:

```
class UserPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  UserPageState createState() => UserPageState();
}

class UserPageState extends State<UserPage>{
  String userName;
  String userEmail;
  String collegeName;

  Future _infoInit() async {
    userName = await HelperFunctions.getUserNamePreference();
    userEmail = await HelperFunctions.getUserEmailPreference();
    collegeName = await HelperFunctions.getUserCollegePreference();
  }

  Widget userScaffold(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text(
              userName
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        ),
        body:Center(
            child: Text("This is User Page")
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _infoInit(),
        builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot) => userScaffold(context, snapshot)
    );
  }
}
```

At the moment the only part I've written is showing the currently logged in user on the app bar, and when I run the code, it seems that it's successfully running. However, when I look at the android studio console I could see that it's actually facing and error which I think is related to async function executed in the FutureBuilder widget.

[image]

```
Error Message:
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device iPhone 11...
Reloaded 7 of 650 libraries in 397ms.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#772f1):
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 298 pos 10: 'data != null'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  FutureBuilder<dynamic> file:///Users/nossu3751/Downloads/flutter_project/moim_app/lib/user/profile.dart:39:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new Text (package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart:298:10)
#3      UserPageState.userScaffold (package:moimapp/user/profile.dart:26:18)
#4      UserPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:moimapp/user/profile.dart:41:54)
#5      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:732:55)
#6      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
```

More exactly, it says that the userName that I'm trying to use in the FutureBuilder is null, even though I believe I assigned the value already through running _infoInit() method and it does actually show correctly on the simulator.

I would really appreciate it if someone can let me know what I'm doing wrong here, and what I can do to stop this message from appearing again. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ConnectionState inside your builder. Look at this code template: (Currently your builder return userScaffold without waiting for the future to complete)

```
return FutureBuilder(
        future: yourFuture(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // future complete
            // if error or data is false return error widget
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return _buildErrorWidget('SOMETHING WENT WRONG, TAP TO RELOAD');
            }

            // return data widget
            return _buildDataWidget();

            // return loading widget while connection state is active
          } else
            return _buildLoadingWidget();
        },
      );
```

Comment: Nice one, helped me a lot here!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the FutureBuilder's `builder` method is invoked each time the AsyncSnapshot is changed (and, initially, the snapshot has no data). Therefore, in the first couple of times that `builder` is called, `userName` will be null, thus giving you that error; but after some point, the username will have been fetched, and when the builder function is called you'll see the username on the screen correctly.

The idiomatic way to use FutureBuilder is the following:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: myFuture,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    // Try adding this print to your code to see when this method is being executed!
    print('Building with snapshot = $snapshot');

    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      // return widget with data - in your case, userScaffold
    }
    else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      // return widget informing of error
    }
    else {
      // still loading, return loading widget (for example, a CircularProgressIndicator)
    }
  },
);
```

So, initially, the builder function will be called will be with a snapshot without data (the "else" branch). You'll probably want to show a loading widget in that case. Then, after some time, the Future completes, and the builder function is called with a snapshot having either the data or some error.

Another important thing in your code is that your function `_infoInit` doesn't actually return anything. So, in fact, your FutureBuilder isn't using the data from the AsyncSnapshot (which means that the above snippet will not actually work, since `snapshot.hasData` will never be true). With FutureBuilder, you normally want to build the widget using the data returned by the AsyncSnapshot. Instead, what happens in your code is:

1. FutureBuilder is created. This calls `_infoInit()`, which triggers fetching the data from Firebase;
2. FutureBuilder's builder method is called. It tries using `userName`, but it is null so Flutter shows the failed assertion;
3. `_infoInit()` fetches all the data, and returns a Future (this future is returned automagically because of the `async` clause in the method signature; however, without a `return` clause, it doesn't actually return any data). But despite the Future not having any data, the 3 variables in the state (including `userName`) have been updated, and now contain some data.
4. Since the future passed to the FutureBuilder has completed, the builder method is called again. This time, `userName` has data, so it builds correctly.

It's fine to write the code as you did, but in that case, you don't need to use a FutureBuilder. You could just invoke `_infoInit()` from the widget's `initState()` method (initState is a method called once when the State is first built) and, after the data is fetched, call setState(). Here's how that would look:

```dart
class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  UserPageState createState() => UserPageState();
}

class UserPageState extends State<UserPage> {
  String userName;
  String userEmail;
  String collegeName;
  bool loadingData = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _infoInit();
  }

  // This can be void now, since we're changing the state, rather than returning a Future
  void _infoInit() async {
    String userName = await HelperFunctions.getUserNamePreference();
    String userEmail = await HelperFunctions.getUserEmailPreference();
    String collegeName = await HelperFunctions.getUserCollegePreference();
    setState(() {
      // In theory, we could have just updated the state variables above, but the
      // recommended practice is to update state variables inside setState.
      this.userName = userName;
      this.userEmail = userEmail;
      this.collegeName = collegeName;
      loadingData = false;
    });
  }

  Widget userScaffold(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text(userName),
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        ),
        body: Center(child: Text("This is User Page")));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (loadingData) {
      // We don't have the data yet, so return a widget to indicate some loading state
      return Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
    }
    return userScaffold(context);
  }
}
```

The above snippet doesn't treat for errors in fetching the data, which you'll probably want to do. And to do that, you might use a flag called 'hasError' or something - which ultimately, will give very similar code to how the "idiomatic" FutureBuilder `builder` method is written.

Both are valid approaches; FutureBuilder maybe uses less code (and might be simpler to use if the rest of your code already uses Futures), but ultimately, it's up to your preference.